# Node.js Scraping: Not receiving query string on 302 redirect location

Tags: node.js, curl, header, request, screen-scraping

I've tried Node.js' HTTPS class and also [Mikeal's "request" library](https://github.com/mikeal/request). Either way, when scraping a certain website that returns a `302` response, I can not retrieve the query string parameters. See below for details:

The `location` attribute with `curl` returns something like this:

`https://www.anotsoawesomeurl.com?FOO=&BAR=LOGIN-0004&ETC=60013E52F8A437`

But same thing on NodeJs' HTTPS class returns:

`https://www.anotsoawesomeurl.com`

Any idea what might be the solution to this issue?